# Android Kotlin Generic ViewModelFactory

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, viewmodel, factory

I have two classes that inhereit from `ViewModelProvider.Factory`. The hing is, I have multiple ViewModel and I want to be able to have a generic factory instead of rewriting everything.

My code look like this :

```kotlin
class AViewModelFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return AViewModel() as T
    }
}

class BViewModelFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return BViewModel() as T
    }
}

class AViewModel: ViewModel() {
    // Some code
}

class BViewModel: ViewModel() {
    // Some code
}
```

And when using them :

```kotlin
// Fragment A
val factory = AViewModelFactory()
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[AViewModel::class.java]

// Fragment B
val factory = BViewModelFactory()
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[BViewModel::class.java]
```

Is there a way I could have a generic class (let's say `GenericViewModelFactory` so I can call it like this :

```kotlin
// Fragment A
val factory = GenericViewModelFactory(AViewModel)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[AViewModel::class.java]

// Fragment B
val factory = GenericViewModelFactory(BViewModel)
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[BViewModel::class.java]
```

Comment: If your ViewModel doesn't take any arguments, why are you even building a custom factory? The default factory works just fine for those kinds of ViewModels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your view models doesn't require any dependence you have to use a common factory provided by the framework.

If you need a custom factory in case of provide dependencies or increate instancing speed.
You can create a common factory which has the ability to create any of your modes.

```
class CommonViewModelFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return when(modelClass) {
            AViewModel::class.java -> AViewModel()
            BViewModel::class.java -> BViewModel()
            else -> throw Throwable("Unsupported view model")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I was wondering, is there a way to pass a class as an argument and then instantiate an object of this class ?

Comment: You can use reflection to create an instance of the class to achieve it.